# Unable to install from mythbuntu installation disc

Tags: boot, system-installation, mythbuntu

I cannot install Mythbuntu 12.04.2 64bit.

I have downloaded the image and burnt it to CD, however my computer does not see it as bootable.

Much like the problem presented with this post "https://askubuntu.com/q/175039/190477"

I tried putting the image on USB (via http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) and booting it from the USB drive, however the boot menu does not show the Mythbuntu OS as a bootable option.

My computer will boot windows 7 and Ubuntu OS versions from the CD-Rom without problems and I have selected the correct drive to boot from via f12 each time.

I have tried a earlier version of Mythbuntu 10.01 downloaded via torrents and had the same problems. I have even tried installing the 32 bit version.

My hardware are the folloing:

- motherboard is a Gigabyte ga-p55a-ud3r
- Graphic card Sapphire ATI HD 5450
- RAM 4GB
- hard drive 1.5TB Western Digital greenpower;
- Proccessor intel i5 760;

Comment: how are you burning the image , i mean what are you using to burn it to cd

Comment: Make sure that you are creating the disk properly. Carefully follow the instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto